# How google chrome processes html pages?

Tags: python, networking, proxy, vpn, python-sockets

Browser - Google chrome 
Programming language - python

**prehistory**

So, i request a page using google chrome web browser, i stop this request from sending to network using windivert ( pydivert ), i use my scripts to send this request trough my vpn server, and then vpn server sends me answer ( html page ).

```s
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()
s.setblocking(False)
conn.sendall(data)
```

Then on a client

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
while True:
 data = s.recv(4096)
 if data:
  data2 = data.decode('utf-8')
  print(data2)
  break
```

I receive a html.
**So, the question is, how do i use this html? How do i "answer to a request" of this browser, so it loads this page?**

So, what do i do? Some kind of - adding this page to google chrome cache?

Comment: You should pass the packets through, so that Chrome receives them after the proxy processes it.

Comment: Why are you breaking out of the loop?

Comment: @Barmar What does that mean? "You should pass the packets through", can you explain it more detailed?. I break the loop, because i do this scripts on one machine. ( i send to port 80, and catch on port 80 ;p )

Comment: You're just printing the packets instead of letting them go to the client.

Comment: Yea, found out what was the problem, i just needed to connect my web browser using tcp handshake to my opened socket, and then just send trough this socket a page ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what I was trying to do I just needed to do this -> (I was using Google Chrome, so just downloaded the proxy helper and redirected all packets to my server on my port):

1. connect to the socket
2. handshake and then the server will receive the request, which it will process and send to the internet
3. then server will receive the response (html page) and using the connected socket will send it back to the client

I then got a page that I requested using server to request it.